# Ghosting on Nixie Tube Clock

Tags: transistors, power-engineering, nixie

I have problem with my nixie clock. There are ghosts when changing numbers on the lamps.

I'm using multiplexing with TLP627 opto-coupler to control anodes and NPN MMBTA42 bipolar transistors to control cathodes. Transistors switch at 0.283 ms, TLP627 at approximate time. Extending the switching time did not help. I tried to solve the problem by extending the switching time of the lamps, but it had to be really long was almost 0.2 seconds, but was still ghosting. IN-14 lamp is powered by 180V, the current does not exceed 0.9mA on it. I'm running out of ideas ;(
[image]

Comment: Are you  absolutely sure your scanning logic is correct? I've built nixie tube circuits, and the only thing I've seen vaguely like this was some poor soldering on my part which caused unwanted turn-on of some filaments. The capacitance of the TLP627 is far too low to store enough charge to supply current to a nixie tube for 200 ms.

Comment: Do you have a scope with several probes? If you scope the opto input on one channel and the opto output on the next channel, you should be able to see any lag in the output turning off, wihch would help you isolate the problem. If you don't see any problem there and the waveforms match, move backwards, and scope the transistor input and the opto input and see if they're doing what you expect at turn-on and turn-off.

Comment: Darlington optoisolators can be pretty slow. Try turning the digit drive off for 20usec, updating the segment data  **after** the delay, then turning it on for the next digit. You can also try 180K from each COLx to GND.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very same issue in my design of Nixie clocks. Changing switching time will not help. Try to connect all cathodes to pre-bias voltage of 100V via e.g. 220K rezistors. To get 100V, design a simple voltage divider from driving 180V.

To get more familiar with the issue, please refer to Section "OFF CATHODE CHARACTERISTICS" at http://www.zapro.dk/public/PDF/nixie/N101.pdf which discusses the magic behind.

Comment: See example at: https://github.com/panzer412/Nixies_Board/blob/master/nixie_clock_schem.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement display blanking during anode switching by setting KAT0...9 to 0 before switching the anode, wait some ms, then switch anode, wait some ms, then set KAT0...9 for proper digit.